# Laravel & Vue: trying to store data with axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, token, csrf, laravel-5.6

**The userflow is like this:**

I'm trying to save data into a laravel backend controller with Axios on the route */api/car/store*, but I'm recieving a 401 HTTP error when emitting the request.

**I think its the Header part...**

I assume I do not have the right header data when I make a request with `axios.post`.

**VUE component method**

```javscript
saveCarDetails(){
    let config = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    let currentObj = this;
    axios.post('/api/car/store', {
        user_id: currentObj.auth_user.id,
        car: currentObj.car
    }, config)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            currentObj = error;
        })
        .then(() => {
            this.errors.clear();
        })
}
```

**Bootstrap.js**

```javascript
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

Console error
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4I5w.png)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to change your middleware in RouteServiceProvider to use web instead of api.

Comment: because the API is not stateless

Comment: But is it possible to use api, if I need to store the data instead for the web